# Error message "APNS Connection Failed: 0", when trying to send push notifications to an iPhone device

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX;

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload))       . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adding write permission for 'everyone' to the .pem file worked for me.